# iphone test iad not visible all the time

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, iad

I have implemented iPhone ads in my app. I get the test ad, but sometimes it takes a while before the test ad appears? Is this normal or should test ad always appear in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@developersaremad is correct. The iAd will only show when there is a successful communication with the apple iAd server and your app recieves a test ad. This simulates real life when the user may not be in a data coverage area and hence cannot get ads.

Answer (score 0):

@Amt-Henning I think its the normal behaviour for the test iAd .